# Bulk insert: JdbcTemplate vs JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, bulkinsert, jdbctemplate

The question want to be really pointed.

I am not interested in knowing in general strengths and weaknesses of the two solutions.

I just need to analyze the performance of the two solutions in the context of **bulk insert**.

That is, with a table like this:

```
create table myEntity
(
    id   bigserial not null,
    name varchar(255) unique,
    primary key (id)
);
```

and this Entity definition:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

if the JPA solution is:

```
// spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 1000 // set by configuration
myEntityRepo.saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)
```

and the JDBC (JdbcTemplate) solution is:

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("""
                        INSERT INTO myEntity(name)
                        VALUES (?)""",
                entities,
                1000,
                (ps, e) -> {
                    ps.setString(1, e.getName());
                });
```

is it normale to have a 15x performance difference between the two approach?

With a local PostgreSQL I'm able to insert 1.000.000 of entities in about 3 seconds using JdbcTemplate, while it takes 45 seconds with JPA.

I'm making something wrong or these are the normal differences that I have to accept?

Comment: I can see the huge difference of 43 seconds which is not normal.
Though it is normal that JPA queries and insertion can be slow than the JDBCTemplate because JPA is just a abstraction layer which hides the complicated things like we do with JDBCTemplate.
Behind the scene JPA does what JDBCTemplate does.

For example
Same query can be slightly faster if you hit in direct database than through your application.

Its a thing about number of layers your data has to pass through.

Comment: I believe the problem is with JPA and the generated ID strategy. But I would like to solve this in a transparent way. Here https://medium.com/@wahyaumau/boost-jpa-bulk-insert-performance-by-90-3a6232d9068d he comes to similar conclusions.